# Create unique list given criteria in another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Image showing my problem graphic

[image]

```
Column B:  Column C:
1             A   
1             A          
1             B        
2             B        
2             C            
3             D     
3             D
```

Is there any way for me to get the value from column C given the value in Column B? E.g what are the unique values in column C given that the value in column B=1?

Comment: Seems like it's a great job for a pivot table!

Comment: A pivot would work if i wasent gonna us it for a drop down menu in another sheet. If Menu1 =1 id only lilke to show ABCDF as options in menu 2. Kind of have to do a "manual" pivot.

Comment: Pivot tables have filters, and they drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA /Macro :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    filterrow = 2 'row of the filter cell
    filtercolumn = 4 'column of the filter cell
    criteriacolumn = 2 'number of column of the criteria list
    firstrow = 2 'first row on the criteria list
    resultcolumn = 5 'number of columns where to show the results
    thecriteria = Target.Value
    Dim critarray() As Variant
    therow = Target.Row
    thecolumn = Target.Column
    lastitem = 0
    wks.Columns(resultcolumn).ClearContents
    If (therow = filterrow) And (thecolumn = filtercolumn) Then
        lastrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, criteriacolumn).End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim critarray(lastrow)
        For i = firstrow To lastrow
            tempcriteria = wks.Cells(i, criteriacolumn)
            templist = wks.Cells(i, criteriacolumn + 1)
            If tempcriteria = Target.Value Then
                repeated = False
                For j = 1 To lastitem
                    a = critarray(j)
                    If a = templist Then
                        repeated = True
                        j = lastrow
                    End If
                Next j
                If repeated = False Then
                    lastitem = lastitem + 1
                    critarray(lastitem) = templist
                    wks.Cells(lastitem, resultcolumn) = templist
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Open VBA / macros using ALT+F11 double click the sheet and paste the code on the right side. There are variables that you can modify to suit the macro to your sheet.

It uses the cell *D2* as the filter value and outputs the result on column *E*.